# What is the difference between RSS and SSR?

Tags: sums-of-squares

According to [this post in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares) the **residual sum of squares (RSS)**, the **sum of squared residuals (SSR)** and the **sum of squared errors of prediction (SSE)** are the same.

[image]

> So the **RSS = SSR = SSE**

Now, according to [this post in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explained_sum_of_squares#Partitioning_in_the_general_OLS_model) the **explained sum of squares (ESS)**, is the same as the **model sum of squares (SSR)**  but the **residual sum of squares (RSS)** is not the same as the **SSR**

[image]

> So here the **ESS = SSR ≠ RSS**?

Comment: The abbreviation "SSR" in the first quote is explained as "sum of squared residuals"; in the second as "sum of squares due to regression". So there's no contradiction.

Comment: I didn't notest that. Thanks. That means that there are not strict names for these in statistical literature? I mean are these abreviations widely used?

Comment: It's often convenient to abbreviate the terms rather than repeat them in full, but there's nothing near enough to a standard abbreviation to justify not giving them in full on first use.